# Creating Python complex nested dictionary from multiple arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have four arrays :

```py
array1 = ["apple","orange","lemon"]
array2 = ["cola","fanta","sprite"]
array3 = ["cookies","sweets","chocolate"]
array4 = ["burger","pizza","pasta"]
```

What I would like to achieve :

```py
complex_dict = {
'apple':[
          [array2],
          [array3],
          [array4]
],
"orange":[
          [array2],
          [array3],
          [array4]
],
"lemon":[
          [array2],
          [array3],
          [array4]
]}
```

I tried to use dictionary comprehension:

```py
complex_dict = {a: [[b],[c],[d]] for a,b,c,d in zip(array1,array2,array3,array4)}
```

Output :

```py
{'apple': [['cola'], ['cookies'], ['burger']], 'orange': [['fanta'], ['sweets'], ['pizza']], 'lemon': [['sprite'], ['chocolate'], ['pasta']]}
```

Which is different from the one that I would like to achieve.
Dear community, kindly ask for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
array1 = ["apple","orange","lemon"]
array2 = ["cola","fanta","sprite"]
array3 = ["cookies","sweets","chocolate"]
array4 = ["burger","pizza","pasta"]

{ a : [array2, array3, array4] for a in array1}
```

Returning:

```
>> {'apple': [
       ['cola', 'fanta', 'sprite'],
       ['cookies', 'sweets', 'chocolate'],
       ['burger', 'pizza', 'pasta']],
    'orange': [
       ['cola', 'fanta', 'sprite'],
       ['cookies', 'sweets', 'chocolate'],
       ['burger', 'pizza', 'pasta']],
    'lemon': [
       ['cola', 'fanta', 'sprite'],
       ['cookies', 'sweets', 'chocolate'],
       ['burger', 'pizza', 'pasta']]}
```